# Is there a way to modify the common behavior of Django forms?

Tags: python, django-forms

I am trying to prevent my forms from always redirecting me to another template or reload the page once data is submitted, but am not exactly sure how to do it

[Take a look at this image as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXueb.png)

When I press the remove icon in the top right corner, the items get removed but I end up getting redirected to cart template:
[Cart template image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCtNr.png)

If possible I want to be able to remove the items and not be redirected to any other page at all, but I can figure out how.

My views:

```
def cart_add(request, product_id):
"""Adds products to the cart or updates existing products"""
    cart = Cart(request)

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 override_quantity=cd['override'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart:cart_detail'))

def cart_remove(request, product_id):
"""Removes items from cart"""
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart:cart_detail'))

def cart_detail(request):
"""Displays the cart and it's items"""
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial= 
                                      {'quantity': item['quantity'],              
                                                'override': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

My urls:

[Urls screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3XTf.png)

Comment: have you tried changing `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart:cart_detail'))` ?

Comment: I did, yes. But all that did was to redirect me to the new url that I would assign it to. If possible I want it to not redirect me at all, but if I get rid of the return then I get an error

Comment: Could you fix the indentation on your code?

Comment: what part of the code specifically? The indentation got screwed up while I was posting the comment so if you could be more specific I will fix it no problem